# Get background image from webpage using DOM XPATH

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm reading a webpage using PHP DOM/XPath and I've managed to get the text I need, but now I'm trying to get the src of the main image but I can't get it.
Also to complicate things, the source is different to the inspector.

Here is the source:

```
<div id="bg">
            <img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

And here is the element in the inspector:

```
<div class="media-player" id="media-player-0" style="width: 320px; height: 320px; background: url(&quot;https://example.com/image.jpg&quot;) center center / cover no-repeat rgb(208, 208, 208);" currentmouseover="16">
```

I've tried:

```
$img = $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(//div[@id=\'bg\']/img, "\')")');
```

and

```
$img = $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class=\'media-player\']/@style, "background: url(\'"), "\')")');
```

but get nothing from either.

Here is my complete code:

```
$html = file_get_contents($externalurl);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $allChildNodesFromDiv = $xpath->query('//h1[@class="artist"]');
    $releasetitle = $allChildNodesFromDiv->item(0)->textContent;
    echo "</br>Title: " . $releasetitle;

    $img = $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(//div[@class=\'media-player\']/@style, "background: url(\'"), "\')")');    
    echo $image;

    $img = $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(//div[@id=\'bg\']/img, "\')")');
    echo $image;
```

Comment: Here is the URL I'm scraping: https://lnk.to/Michael-Gray-Rework and this is what I'm trying to get: 
https://284fc2d5f6f33a52cd9f-ce476c3c56a27f320262daffab84f1af.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/artwork_5e74a44e1e004_CHAMPDL879D_5e74a44e4672b.jpg

Comment: It looks like this data is loaded in javascript, if you save `$html` and then look through that source - `media-player` isn't set anywhere.

Comment: Ah yes, it appears in: `poster : 'https://284fc2d5f6f33a52cd9f-ce476c3c56a27f320262daffab84f1af.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/artwork_5e74a44e1e004_CHAMPDL879D_5e74a44e4672b.jpg'` is there a way to grab that or should I look at something like `stripos()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not something I would normally suggest, but as the particular content you are after is loaded from javascript, BUT the content is in `<script>` tags, then it may be an easy one for a regex to extract.  From your comment...

> Ah yes, it appears in: poster :
>   'https://284fc2d5f6f33a52cd9f-ce476c3c56a27f320262daffab84f1af.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/artwork_5e74a44e1e004_CHAMPDL879D_5e74a44e4672b.jpg'

So this code looks the value of `poster : '...',`.

```
$html = file_get_contents($externalurl);

preg_match("/poster : '(.*)',/", $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

This can be prone to changes in the html, but it may work for now.

Comment: Thanks - that works for me. Any reason why you wouldn't normally suggest it?

Comment: Normally if you are processing HTML tags, regexes are the last thing you should use DOMDocument as you were.  A good post on this is https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1213708